# how to select rows from two tables and one and group them

Tags: sql

I'm wondering about, how could I make a connection between two tables.

I have those two tables `categories` and `news`.

What I want exactly to do is to show `news` by `categories`

so let's say I have three headlines with same `category` which it's `news` in `news_table`

but the news table shows the `category` as an id

so let's say

```
news_table:
id,title,category,date;
1,hello,2,2012

categories_table:
id,category,parent
1,news,0
```

now I want to show the news by category

so it should be like this:

```
cat:news

title              date
title 2             date
title 3            date

cat:general
title          date
title2          date
```

if you please want to see another example just see Google news

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from news_table left join categories_table on news_table.category = categories_table.id where .....
```

You should rename the category column in news_table to category_id for clarity.

You can replace the * with the columns you want from either table.  Be sure to use the table name.column name if any column names are ambiguous.

Comment: thanks friend i'm facing another problem now
when i fetch the news i get each headline has the category
how can i fetch maybe 4 headlines inside the category ?